# Action mailer - Sending an email through a contact form with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using `Ruby 2.6.3` and `Rails 5.2`. I want to make a contact form on my website, with a box for user email address, and a box for the message content. When a user fill those boxes and click on "Submit", i would like that it send me an email. No need for the user to sign up or anything.

My website is a one page website, i don't have any models, and i just have 1 controller : `pages_controller.rb`.

I used the documentation on [Action mailer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) but i didn't suceed.

Here are the steps i followed :

```
rails generate mailer ContactMailer
```

**config/environments/development.rb** :

```
config.action_mailer.default charset: 'utf-8'
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true    
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.mail.yahoo.com",
    port: 465,
    domain: "yahoo.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "myemailaddress@yahoo.com",
    password: "********"
  }
```

**app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb** :

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "from@example.com"
  def contact(message)
    @message = message
    mail(to: 'myemailaddress@yahoo.com', subject: 'Test')
  end
end
```

**app/views/contact_mailer/contact.html.erb** :

```
<p>Hello world</p>
<%= @message %>
```

**app/controllers/pages_controller.rb** :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
  def send_contact
     ContactMailer.contact(params[:message]).deliver
  end
end
```

**app/views/pages/home.html.erb** :

```
<form action="/send_contact" method="post">
   <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="Your email">
   <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**config/routes.rb** :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  post "send_contact" => "pages#send_contact"
end
```

This is supposed to send me an email when clicking on submit. Instead, i get this error : `EOFError in PagesController#send_contact end of file`

So i tried with a gmail address with the right username / password and the right config :

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    user_name: ENV["USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["PASSWORD"]
  }
```

And i have this error : `535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.`. I tried to allow "less secure apps" and desactivate 2FA. I also tried to generate an app specific password. Same error.

I don't understand what is going on.

**EDIT** :

When i printed `ENV["USERNAME"]` i didn't have what i wrote in my `.env` file. I had instead my first name, i don't know why. So i changed my `.env` file to `MAIL_USERNAME` (instead of `USERNAME`) and now it's working in development, but unfortunately i get an error 500 in production, and i have no idea how to debug this.

**EDIT 2** :

Problem solved ! I just had to add my .env variables in [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail used to allow simply passing your valid email and password via a Rails app in order to send emails.  But they killed that functionality off, and require that you configure an App Specific Password for this purpose:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

I think the change came in 2018 or so, I remember that our Rails app was humming along just fine and suddenly it stopped sending messages.  At that time, it wasn't widely announced by Gmail that they had made this change, if announced at all, which caught us off guard.

Create your app specific password and use those credentials.  See if that starts sending emails for you.  Your code looks fine.

I've never been able to successfully use a Yahoo account with a Rails app by the way.

Comment: I had to enable 2FA to be able to configure an App Specific Password. I tried and i still have the same issue : `535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.`. I also tried with outlook, that doesn't work neither. The problem must come from my rails code i guess

Comment: The error message you showed is coming from Gmail to be sure.  It means that the email is sent, hits the mail server, and is rejected for authentication reasons.  I think your app specific password setup is off, because your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks, i solved partially my problem (see my post). You were right about the app specific password. I managed to send mail through my app, but only in development. When i do it in production, i have an error 500 and i have no idea how to debug this. Yet, i have the same config code in `production.rb`. Any idea ?

Comment: My question is where are you running this in production?  Are you sure your production .env values are correct?  You may require some authorization in the Gmail interface as the message from Prod is going to be coming from a different host.  If you would please accept my answer as the solution I would appreciate it :)

Comment: I don't understand your question. When i say in production, i mean i tried to send a mail directly through my website (mini-circuit-electrique.fr) after pushing (with heroku). If you try yourself you will see the error 500 after clicking on submit on the contact form. Which authorizations are you talking about ?

Comment: Heroku is the key element I was missing - https://blog.heroku.com/tech_sending_email_with_gmail I run apps on Heroku also - they don't care about your .env file with Rails.  You need to set the config variables for Heroku according to the link I just pasted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! It works :) I just added config variables directly in heroku dashboard as indicated on this page : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars .